# SQL join and concatenation

Tags: sql, join

```
select * from [stage].[dbo].[Stage_PolicySection] as Trg_Stg_policySection;
select  Cast (Dim_Policy.MasterNumber + Dim_Policy.MasterSeq as nvarchar) 
as PolicyKey  
from Dimension.Policy
Join [Dimension].[Policy] as Dim_Policy on 
Trg_Stg_policySection.PolicyKey = Dim_Policy;
```

here i need to join `masternumber` and `masterseq` and then i can join with `dimpolicy`, because `dimpolicy` dont have policy key and can only be get by joining `masternumber` and `masterseq` but if concatenate them i m getting below error please help me

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 12 
>   The multi-part identifier "Dim_Policy.MasterNumber" could not be bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 12 
>   The multi-part identifier "Dim_Policy.MasterSeq" could not be bound.

Answer (score 1):

Your inner select references Dim_policy which is [an alias that is] not in scope for that inner select.  Only the table in the FROM clause of that inner select is in scope.